# Can you automatically parse JSON into an SQL Sever?

Tags: sql-server, json

I have a **JSON** file of data which I have pulled from an *API* and I would very much like to just dump this data into an **SQL Server**.

The reason it's SQL Server specifically is that the database is already in place for the current project. I have spent time googling this and searching on here but was unable to find anything useful thus far. I'm familiar with Python but I'm open to any solution.

TLDR: I'm interested in which languages and packages provide easy solutions to automate JSON to an SQL Server table, do you have any suggestions or know of any packages that already achieve this?

Comment: well if you don't want to parse it on your SQL Server, just dump it and then get it back, than varchar(max) column will work ok.

Comment: hmm programmatically this should take you no more than 20 lines, [https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2013/03/26/sql-server-json-to-table-and-table-to-json/](https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2013/03/26/sql-server-json-to-table-and-table-to-json/)

Comment: nafas this would require me to understand the structure of the JSON file would it not? The file I have is huge, complicated and I don't want to have to understand the information unless this is the only way. Maybe I've misunderstood the link though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like [SSIS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx) to accomplish this (you may already have it) by writing a script task. This could do custom parsing then load it into the correct table. This can be easily automated. I mention SSIS because it's very easy to add future tasks to this, if you're ever required.

Alternatively you could create a script outside of the database (ie. Python) that parses the JSON, connects to the database through ODBC/OLEDB and writes the records. This can be automated using Task Scheduler or something similar. An example implementation of this could use [PYODBC](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/).

Comment: Aye, I've passed an xml file and the xml schema over to the database team now and they've done the SSIS way. I was hoping I could just pass XML into a script that would kick out the database but alas.

Answer (score 0):

you can use WCF Web Service, sending json data to SQL Server .

refer the links below hope it will be helpful for you

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/167159/How-to-create-a-JSON-WCF-RESTful-Service-in-sec

http://mikesknowledgebase.azurewebsites.net/pages/Services/WebServices-Page2.htm

you cant directly fetch json data's in sql server instead  you can use wcf service